# Unable to Process Request when posting In App Purchase ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a weird problem in posting iOS In App Purchase file. I already do the steps like in `[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html][1]`

the status is "Ready to Submit", but when I click into the table, it give me this warning message Unable to Process Request

> Your request could not be processed. For additional help, send an
>   email to itunesconnect@apple.com.

it's really weird, since I can do this on my last app. Can somebody give me a clue?

thx

Comment: is it itune connect ? problem ?? how long its been you r having this problem

Comment: yes it is ItunesConnect, 2 days :(

Comment: "click into the table"?